# Animación en Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy intentando animar el textAlign de un texto, de forma que vaya desde start a end indefinidamente.

Me encuentro con dos problemas:

- No sé como animar un textAlign
- Cómo hacer que una animación no dependa de una variable, sino que se realice desde el principio y de forma repetida?

El texto que querría animar sería el siguiente:

```
    Text(
        text = "TEXTO...",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start
    )
```

Gracias!!

Comment: Hola, recuerda que es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste y edita tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes pensarlo de otra manera. No tienes idea de cómo animarlo porque la alineación que se usa en `Text` se basa en valores que no tienen correlación alguna con un valor que represente una continuidad. Por ejemplo si revisas el archivo `TextAlign.kt` donde están definidas las alineaciones verías que:

- `TextAlign.Start` = `TextAlign(5)`
- `TextAlign.Center` = `TextAlign(3)`
- `TextAlign.End` = `TextAlign(6)`

Como puedes ver los números entre paréntesis no representan lo que se conoce como bias horizontal. Pero si envuelves el `Text` dentro de un `Column`, sí lo podrías hacer ya que la alineación del componente `Column` sí representa la posición con un bias horizontal.

Si abres el archivo `Aligment.kt` donde están definidas las diferentes alineaciones que usa `Column` verías lo siguiente:

```
// 1D Alignment.Horizontals.
@Stable
val Start: Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(-1f)
@Stable
val CenterHorizontally: Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(0f)
@Stable
val End: Horizontal = BiasAlignment.Horizontal(1f)
```

Entonces ahora solo quedaría animar el valor que el bias horizontal recibe como parámetro y que iría de `-1f` a `1f`.

Puedes ver cómo se hacen las animaciones infinitas en la documentación oficial [aquí](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#rememberinfinitetransition).

Quedaría así:

```
val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
val bias by infiniteTransition.animateValue(
    initialValue = -1f,
    targetValue = 1f,
    typeConverter = Float.VectorConverter,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = tween(1000, easing = LinearEasing),
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
    )
)
```

Cambia la duración de la animación y el tipo de `easing` a tu gusto. Luego teniendo el valor almacenado en `bias` se lo pasas a `BiasAlignment.Horizontal` para convertirlo en el objeto que necesitas pasarle a la alineación horizontal:

```
val alignment by derivedStateOf { BiasAlignment.Horizontal(bias) }
```

Y por último usas la alineación en el `Column` que envuelve al texto:

```
Column(
    Modifier.wrapContentHeight().fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = alignment
) {
    Text(
        text = "TEXTO...",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
    )
}
```